# How can I use albumentions (python package) in ros2 node

Tags: ros2, python

**I tried to import the Albumentations package into my ROS 2 workspace with support from rosdep as follows:**

## 1. Init and install rosdep

Details at: [Managing Dependencies with rosdep](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Intermediate/Rosdep.html#what-is-rosdep)

## 2. Add dependencies in package.xml of my ROS2 package

My package.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>my_package</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="user@gmail.com">root</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>
  
  <depend>python3-albumentations-pip</depend>
   
  <test_depend>ament_copyright</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_flake8</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_pep257</test_depend>
  <test_depend>python3-pytest</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_python</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

## 3. rosdep install packages

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y
```

The output after installing Albumentations successfully:

```
#All required rosdeps installed successfully
```

## 4. Build the package

```
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
colcon build --merge-install --symlink-install my_package
```

## 5. Run the node

After performing the above actions and running the ROS 2 node in my_package, an error still occurs as follows:

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from cv_bridge import CvBridge
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
import cv2
import torch
import albumentations as A
```

The output:

```
File "/workspaces/ROS2_ws/build/my_package/my_package/node.py", line 9, in <module>
    import albumentations as A
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'albumentations'
```

Before installing the Albumentations package, I had successfully installed the PyTorch library in my workspace using the same steps as mentioned above, but it doesn't work with Albumentations.

**Please help me overcome this difficult situation. Looking forward to your response.
I apologize for being new to using ROS2.**

Comment: "The output after installing Albumentations successfully:" It would be very helpful to show  how this was installed and where. And how you're including that pip environment in your active one to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The most possible problem is your current directory when running `rosdep install`, if you are in the workspace directory run it with `--from-paths src`. However, if you are in the `src` already run it with `--from-paths .` I tried it on my local machine and it worked so I can't think of any other problem.

Comment: Plus 1 for going through the actual steps as test.